# dfsummary() from summarytools package has random backslashes in the values of freqs column

Tags: r, r-markdown, summarytools

When using dfsummary() from the summarytools package on a factor vector, the values in freqs column have random backslashes at the start.
[Please see this output image.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qd0YX.png)

This is the code:

```
x <- factor(c("Tertiary_pattern_3", "Tertiary_pattern_5", "Tertiary_pattern_5", "Tertiary_pattern_5", "Tertiary_pattern_4", "Tertiary_pattern_5", "Tertiary_pattern_5", "Tertiary_pattern_4", "Tertiary_pattern_5", "Tertiary_pattern_5", "Tertiary_pattern_5", "Tertiary_pattern_5", "Tertiary_pattern_5", "Tertiary_pattern_4", "Tertiary_pattern_2", "Tertiary_pattern_5", "Tertiary_pattern_5", "Tertiary_pattern_4", "Tertiary_pattern_5", "Tertiary_pattern_5", "Tertiary_pattern_5", "Tertiary_pattern_5", "Tertiary_pattern_5", "Tertiary_pattern_5", "Tertiary_pattern_5", "Tertiary_pattern_5", "Tertiary_pattern_5", "Tertiary_pattern_5", "Tertiary_pattern_4", "Tertiary_pattern_5"))
print(kable(dfSummary(x,
            graph.col    = FALSE,
            style        = "grid",
            plain.ascii  = FALSE
            ),
            method = "render") %>%
      kable_styling('bordered', bootstrap_options = c("striped", "hover", "condensed")),'\n\n')
```

The input to dfsummary is a factor vector.
The above image is just one example, I am facing this issue in almost every case in which a factor vector is involved. However, I don't face this issue when the vector is numeric or date.
I am using this chunk of code in a r markdown file and knitting to html.

[Output image for the exact above code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5xIeQ.png)

Comment: Can you provide your dataset so we can reproduce this error? See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: @jrcalabrese I have added a small subset of my data and attached an image of output for it

Comment: Note that your example also depends on the `kableExtra` package. In addition, when I ran it, I got an error message `Error in pryr::where(obj_name) : length(name) == 1 is not TRUE`, so my plot output is not the same as what you've shared.